# Browse encrypted sqlite DB encrypted by objective c's NSData

Tags: objective-c, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

We have a sqlite ver 3 DB encrypted by a `NSData` Key and the "key" is stored in the device key chain. We have no problems decrypting the DB using Objective C code. However, we want to ship the DB for support diagnosis and we need the key from key chain also shipped so that support can open the DB using DB Browser for sqlite. When I try to read the "key" from key store, it comes in as `NSData`. I tried converting `NSData` to `NSString` using all the encodings in `initWithData` method but the string is coming up garbled. How do I get a string representation of this "Key" so that I can use it to open the DB using "DB Explorer for sqlite" and enter the "password" in the dialog? The value of the `NSData` key is:

```
_cfinfo is char[4] with values: [0]:\f, [1]:\x14, [2]:\0, [3]:\0, _rc:3, length: 16
```

Got this info while debugging.
Thanks

Comment: Show content of your data object in hex values.

Comment: I solved it by copying the encrypted database as a new file and rekeying the copied database using a new password ["rekey" option is provided by sqlite]. I used a "string" based key for "rekey" and it works nicely without disturbing the original databases keychain based password.